# Is there a limit to the number of nested replace commands?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, nested

Due to the way information is stored in the ASSIGNEES column of our tables, (see below)

```
ASSIGNEES
Application__bDevelopers e502488 e531146 e551624
Application__bDevelopers e502488 Server__bAdmins e547653
e547653
e252403 e537149
e255401 e466840 Desktop__bSupport
e263899 e284429 Harbor__uSchool__bIT
e451155 e566548 c115478 e403190 e518202 Clinical__bApplications
Server__bAdmins e547653 Desktop__bSupport
IMAC__b__PInstall__bMove__bAdd__bChange__p e403190
....
```

I have to use the following nested replace command when trying to produce a result set:

```
......    
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
REPLACE(ASSIGNEES COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS,'__b',' ') 
,'__P','(')
,'__p',')')
,'__3','#')
,'__7','&')
,'__d','.')
,'__f','/')
,'__u','-')
,'__A','+')
,'__M',',')
,'e135164','Angela Martin')
,'e214652','Rosie Mayer')
,'e917868','Jon Bugen')
,'e619276','Phil Garcia')
,'e127172','Elie Esco')
,'e970795','Mary Morales')
......
```

My question is: Is there a limit to the number of replace commands that can be nested like this?  I have nearly a 1000 user ids (e.g., e123456) that need to be translated into the names of the users.)

There's has to be a better way of doing this.  Perhaps "CROSS APPLY"?  I'm open to all suggestions.  Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why someone will store information like this

Comment: are all the user id's fixed in length?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the limit on nesting is 32.  Unfortunately, the documentation explicitly gives this for stored procedures and subqueries (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx), but the error message suggests that it applies to functions as well.  You should probably write a UDF to clean the data.

Comment: That's a giant mess.  How about putting those rules in a table and just joining to that table to do your replace?

Comment: "There's has to be a better way of doing this."  Yes.  It's a) not storing data in an encoded format.  When you want to store a right parentheses, you store `)`, not `__p`, and b) not storing multiple values in the same field.  When you want to store Rosie Mayer's ID, you store `e214652` in a field by itself.  Then, in another table, you map Rosie Mayer to `e214652`.  Your data is *extremely* de-normalized.  Your *application* needs to store data in a usable format.

Comment: @vkp - userid's are not necessarily fixed in length.

Comment: @Bacon Bits - Unfortunately, I have no way of controlling how the data is written to the DB.  Our ticket-tracking application does this.  I'm simply running queries on it.  I'll be sure to let our vendor know.

Answer (score 2):

Nesting limit?  Your question really intrigued me!

The example below shows you can nest functions up to 244 levels.  When I add one more LEFT I get the error:

Msg 191, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.

Have you considering breaking the data into multiple fields?  You'll find it much easier to interact with.

Example

```
/* There are ten functions to row. 
 * Tested up to nest level 244 without error.
 * 245 returns "Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries."
 * Tested SQL Server 2008 R2.
 */
SELECT                               
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(  -- 100
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(  -- 200
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(  -- 240
    LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(                               -- 244
        'x'
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1), 1)
    , 1), 1), 1), 1)
;
```

Comment: For UDF the limit is 32: [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx): `User-defined functions can be nested up to 32 levels`

Comment: Good point.  The limit of 32 also applies to SPs and subqueries.  @Gordon Linoff's comment on OP has a great link to other SQL Server limits.

Comment: @destination-data - yes, i have considered that.  but not really sure how.

Comment: @Sung Can you create your own tables, or are you looking for a read only solution?

Comment: I have the rights to create tables, but would rather not.  A read-only solution would be ideal.  Creating a VIEW on the other hand is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is horrible. You want to hard code the mapping of every username!?

Whatever you are trying to do, the replacements above can be done within one REGEX.

You should clean this up by regular expression and use a mapping table (id,username).

Comment: we already have another table that has the mapping for userid to username etc.  but how could I use that table in this situation where there are multiple Assignees in a column?

Comment: you could LEFT JOIN your mapping table m and check if ASSIGNEES (pattern)matches the m.ID ... but I would really try to get rid of THAT data structure at all!